# Convert Series to Dataframe where series index is Dataframe column names

Tags: pandas

I am selecting row by row as follows:

```
for i in range(num_rows):
    row = df.iloc[i]
```

as a result I am getting a Series object where `row.index.values` contains names of `df` columns.

But I wanted instead dataframe with only one row having dataframe columns in place.

When I do `row.to_frame()` instead of `1x85` dataframe (1 row, 85 cols) I get `85x1` dataframe where index contains names of columns and `row.columns`
outputs

`Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')`.

But all I want is just original data-frame columns with only one row. How do I do it?
Or how do I convert `row.index` values to `row.column` values and change `85x1` dimension to `1x85`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to adding `T`

```
row.to_frame().T
```

Also change your for loop with adding `[]`

```
for i in range(num_rows):
    row = df.iloc[[i]]
```